# Error :Cannot Find Table 0

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am seeing an error regarding `cannot find table 0`, where the dataset doesn't contain the table data. This is my code to fetch rows from a table:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection sqlconnection;
    sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"connectionstring");
    sqlconnection.Open();
    string sql = "Select (supplier_id,name) from supplier_info where supplier_id= '"+supplierid+"'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlconnection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet dtset = new DataSet();
    adpt.Fill(dt);
    dt = dtset.Tables[0];
    DataRow dr;
    dr = dt.Rows[0];
    sqlconnection.Close();
    return dr;
```

Business logic code:

```
  Cust_datalogic dc = new Cust_datalogic(); //datalogic class
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  DataRow dr;
  dr=dc.GetSupplierInfo(id);    //method 
  Supplier_BLL bc = new Supplier_BLL();  //business logic class
  bc.Ssup_ID = dr[0].ToString();
  bc.Ssup_name = dr[1].ToString();
  return bc;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem area in your code is

```
adpt.Fill(dt);  //You are filling dataTable 
dt = dtset.Tables[0]; // You are assigning Table[0] which is null or empty
```

Change it to

```
adpt.Fill(dtset); //Fill Dataset
dt = dtset.Tables[0]; //Then assign table to dt
```

### OR

Your can directly use SqlDataAdapter to Fill DataTable thus no need of DataSet.

Just remove DataSet, use

```
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adpt.Fill(dt);
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
```

Comment: it's just beacuse you dont have any records to return check before assigning to datarow check for records like this if(dt.rows.count>0)
{
//assign data to row
}

Comment: @BhargavAmin, Check as sharad has pointed out do you have rows. Just debug and see what is the value of `dt.rows.count`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when calling to web service method. Issue was with the filter / Query condition. What I was looking for it was not exist in the database. So, check if the required data exists in database.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add a select statement after the insert query.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).